# Graph objects has no attribute nodes

Tags: python, api, networking, routes

I know this is probably a very simple fix but can anyone spot why i'm being told type object 'Graph' has no attribute 'nodes'
It is refering to the line "if name not in Graph.nodes"

```
def addrouter(name: AddRouter):
if name not in Graph.nodes:
    Graph.add_node(name)
    return "success"
else:
    return "Error, node already exists"
```

This is my add node function

```
   def add_node(self, name):
   if name in self.nodes:
            return -1

    self.nodes.append(name)
    return 0
```

And here  is the graph class

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
    self.nodes = []
    self.edges = []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graph is a class. You need to create a new instance of the Graph class and operate on it.

```
my_graph = Graph()
if name not in my_graph.nodes:
```

You also don't necessarily need the if statement, as your `add_node` function already handles checking the list for the name.